# How to use thrust::transform on larger Vector derived from smaller Vector?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Input and starting arrays:

```
dv_A = { 5, -3, 2, 6} //4 elements
dv_B = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Expected output:

```
dv_B = { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
```

For every element in `dv_A{}`, there are `(dv_A.size - 1)` elements in `dv_B{}`. This is because each element of `dv_A` should have a child element in `dv_B` for each of the *other* `dv_A` elements (i.e. should exclude itself). Therefore, if there are 4 elements in `dv_A`, there should be 3 elements in `dv_B` for each of the `dv_A` elements.

I want to transform each `dv_B` element to have a value of `1` if its corresponding `dv_A` element has a value `> 0`. Correspondence is determined based on the position of the element in `dv_B`. For example:

The first 3 `dv_B` values will be transformed by the value in `dv_A[0]`,
The second 3 `dv_B` values will be transformed by the value in `dv_A[1]`,
Etc.

Here's my attempt so far

```
thrust::transform(
    dv_B.begin(),
    dv_B.end(),
    thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        dv_A.begin(),
        _1 % dv_A
    ), 
    dv_B.begin(),
    _2 > 0 //When 2nd argument is greater than 0 then set the position in dv_A to 1.
);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can nest `counting_iterator`, `transform_iterator` (`i / (A_size - 1)`) and `permutation_iterator` to get the view into `dv_A` that you need to do the transform.

Comment: @paleonix I think that's what I'm after, but just can't get it to work. Updated my code with my best attempt before nesting the iterators, which I could not get to work either.

Comment: https://c.godbolt.org/z/1beh3e3sP untested, but compiles.

Comment: @paleonix that works-- turn it into an answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial code could look something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dv_b.size(); i++){
    const int readIndex = i / (dv_a.size() - 1);
    if(dv_a[readIndex] > 0) dv_b[i] = 1;
    else dv_b[i] = 0;
}
```

which can easily be written using `for_each`. I think this makes the code more clear compared to using transform together with various fancy iterators.

```
thrust::for_each(
    thrust::device,
    thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
    thrust::make_counting_iterator(0) + dv_b.size(),
    [
     s = dv_a.size() - 1,
     dv_a = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_a.data()),
     dv_b = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_b.data())
    ] __device__ (int i){
        const int readIndex = i / s;
        if(dv_a[readIndex] > 0) dv_b[i] = 1;
        else dv_b[i] = 0;
    }
);
```

Comment: This is more readable than the nested iterator idea from @paleonix's original comment on my post. One slight code improvement on this is to remove the if() in the last argument and naively set dv_b[i] = dv_a[readIndex] > 0 to eliminate the conditional (since >0 will return 1, and <=0 will return 0 anyway).

Comment: @aiwyn I don't think shortening the if is a code improvement. The way it is now clearly expresses that the value should be 1, not just the implicit conversion of a boolean value to int (which happens to be 1). In any case, the resulting ptx code is the same, anyways.

Comment: You're right, looks like the compiler handles it the same. Also, this version of the solution is 4x faster than the other one so I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Packing the fancy iterator creation into an appropriately named factory function makes this version quite readable as well. Especially if you need this kind of pattern more than once, this solution might be more elegant.

```cpp
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

#include <iostream>

// nvcc doesn't seem to like __device__ or __host__ __device__ lambdas in auto
// return types, so I defined this functor instead
template <typename T>
class Div {
    T div_{};
    public:
    Div(T div) : div_{div} {}
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T in) const noexcept { return in / div_; }
};

// I stole "repeat" from numpy. Another version using modulo (%) and therefore
// repeating the whole input instead of single elements would be called "tile".
template <class It>
auto make_repeat_it_begin(It input, int repetitions) {
    using diff_t = typename It::difference_type;
    return thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                input,
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                    thrust::make_counting_iterator(diff_t{0}),
                    Div{static_cast<diff_t>(repetitions)}));
}

int main() {
    int A[] = {5, -3, 2, 6};
    constexpr int size_A = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);

    thrust::host_vector<int> hv_A(A, A + size_A);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_A(hv_A);
    thrust::device_vector<int> dv_B(size_A * (size_A - 1));

    auto A_repeat_it = make_repeat_it_begin(dv_A.begin(), size_A - 1);
    
    thrust::transform(A_repeat_it, A_repeat_it + dv_B.size(), 
                      dv_B.begin(),
                      [] __device__ (int a){ return a > 0 ? 1 : 0; });

    thrust::host_vector<int> hv_B(dv_B);
    thrust::copy(hv_B.begin(), hv_B.end(),
                 std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
}
```

Due to the device lambda, `nvcc` needs the `-extended-lambda` flag.

Comment: Thank you, I'll compare this with @Abator 's solution.